# ImageMagick Ouput GIF

Tags: imagemagick

How can I make this output a GIF instead of a PNG:

```
convert GIF.gif ( +clone -alpha extract -virtual-pixel black -spread 10 -blur 0x3 -threshold 50% -spread 1 -blur 0x.7 ) -alpha off -compose Copy_Opacity -composite torn_paper.png
```

Comment: Simply replace .png with .gif on your output image.

Comment: It outputs a frozen GIF. Before: https://gyazo.com/a8e97621b7d237236bb420addfe9149e After: https://gyazo.com/542151d164cc201795ef56c64b4de67d

Comment: That command processes a single image not an animation. You will have to write a script loop over each frame of your gif and then combine them at the end.

Comment: How can I do this with ImageMagick?

Comment: You need do it one frame at a time with your command. Then combine all the frames into your animated gif.  You can do the first part with a script loop. But I do not use Windows, so cannot help with scripting on that platform.